# A link not always working on first try

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, magento-1.9

This is something quite bizarre that I can't seem to explain.

On my magento shop I created a link to the content area and it's a simple a href link. Though sometimes when you click the link you just end up on the shop again, instead of following the link.

Page that this is happening on: http://www.musculi.com/ 
link I'm trying to click and that should redirect to /content is "Articles, Athletes and More" (the blue button)

Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
<li class="nav-item level0 level-top right">
    <a class="level-top" href="http://musculi.com/content" title="Musculi Content: Articles, News &amp; more">
        <span>onze atleten, nieuws en meer</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

EDIT: This one minute video illustrates my problem: (once the link works, it keeps working until you clear your cache, then it works on the second or third time it gets clicked)

https://youtu.be/uyrmXK-RBR8

Comment: works for me - but it looks like you have some sort of language redirection going on as although you are linking to /content, I end up at content/en.  Perhaps it's something to do with magento not picking up the locale of your computer.  You may want to add the magento tag to your question

Comment: @Pete in any browser (I tried Chrome, Firefox and IE) when you clear your cache and history,.. the link only works the second time you click it

Comment: Sorry, can't replicate your error - works first time in all browsers for me - however I never hit the 'content/en' page as the page is blocked by my companies spam site filters - this may be causing you to redirect back to the homepage?  Again, if you add magento tag to your question, people with more experience with megento may have experienced this sort of behaviour and be able to offer a better answer

Comment: @Pete I added a 1min video to show the problem